# Ember - Switch from one state to another's nested state

Tags: ember.js, nested, ember-old-router

I have the following code. (I'll just copy the router, since the application has arround 500 lines at the moment)
What I need, is to switch from state 'rooms' to 'guests.new'.

When i get to rooms state, it loads a template where i call the action 'newGuest' in order to change the state to the 'newGuest' screen. But i can't get it to work.
On firebug I get this error:

```
g[a] is undefined
```

Here's the router code.
Hope you can help me.

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
        enableLogging:true,
        location:'hash',
        gotoRooms:Ember.Route.transitionTo('rooms.index'),
        gotoGuests:Ember.Route.transitionTo('guests.index'),
        gotoBookings:Ember.Route.transitionTo('bookings'),
        gotoHome:Ember.Route.transitionTo('root.index'),

        root:Ember.Route.extend({
            index:Ember.Route.extend({
                route:'/',
                connectOutlets:function (router) {
                    App.HomeView.appendTo('#main-content .container_12');
                },
                enter: function(){
                    console.log('Entro Home');
                },
                exit: function(){
                    App.HomeView.remove();
                }
            }),
            guests:Ember.Route.extend({
                route:'/guests',
                index:Ember.Route.extend({
                    route:'/',
                    connectOutlets:function(router) {
                        App.GuestsView.appendTo('#main-content .container_12');    
                    },
                    enter: function(){
                        console.log("Entro Guests");
                    },
                    exit: function(){
                        App.GuestsView.remove();
                    },
                }),
                new:Ember.Route.extend({
                    route:'/new/:bed',
                    deserialize: function(manager, params) {
                        console.log('New Guest \nBed:'+params['bed']+"\n Date:"+params['date']);
                        App.GuestView.appendTo('#main-content .container_12');
                    },
                    connectOutlets:function(){
                        alert("hola");
                    },
                    exit: function(){
                        App.GuestsView.newGuestView.remove();
                    }
                })
            }),
            rooms:Ember.Route.extend({
                newGuest:Ember.Route.transitionTo('guests.new'),
                route:'/rooms',
                index:Ember.Route.extend({
                    route:'/',                    
                    connectOutlets:function(router) {
                        App.RoomsView.appendTo('#main-content .container_12');    
                    },
                    enter: function(){
                        console.log("Entro Rooms");
                    },
                    exit: function(){
                        App.RoomsView.remove();
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    });
```

Thanks @Akash, but it's still not working.
I'm using ember-1.0.pre.
The template that calls 'newGuest' is the following:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="rooms">
      {{#each room in App.Rooms}}
        <div class="grid_4">
      <div class="block-border">
        <div class="block-header">
          <h1>{{room.screen}}</h1><span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
          <ul class="block-list">
          {{#each bed in room.camas}}
            {{#if bed.guestId}}
            <li {{action "viewGuest" on="click"}} class="occupied">{{bed.id_guest}}</li>
            {{else}}
            <li class="free" {{action "newGuest" on="click"}}>Free Bed</li>
            {{/if}}
          {{/each}}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      {{/each}}
    </script>
```

I've also tried with ember-latest, since i've read in various threads that pre version gave some routing issues.
Now turns out that with ember-latest, i can't define computed properties. At least that's what pops up on the console when loading the page.

Any clue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Ember doesn't have access to the `guests` route from within the `rooms` route. So have you need to do is move the action function lower down the tree. I have tweaked your code a bit below:

**Tweaked Code:**

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
        enableLogging:true,
        location:'hash',
        gotoRooms:Ember.Route.transitionTo('rooms.index'),
        gotoGuests:Ember.Route.transitionTo('guests.index'),
        gotoBookings:Ember.Route.transitionTo('bookings'),
        gotoHome:Ember.Route.transitionTo('root.index'),

        root:Ember.Route.extend({
            newGuest:Ember.Route.transitionTo('guests.new'),
            index:Ember.Route.extend({
                route:'/',
                connectOutlets:function (router) {
                    App.HomeView.appendTo('#main-content .container_12');
                },
                enter: function(){
                    console.log('Entro Home');
                },
                exit: function(){
                    App.HomeView.remove();
                }
            }),
            guests:Ember.Route.extend({
                route:'/guests',
                index:Ember.Route.extend({
                    route:'/',
                    connectOutlets:function(router) {
                        App.GuestsView.appendTo('#main-content .container_12');    
                    },
                    enter: function(){
                        console.log("Entro Guests");
                    },
                    exit: function(){
                        App.GuestsView.remove();
                    },
                }),
                new:Ember.Route.extend({
                    route:'/new/:bed',
                    deserialize: function(manager, params) {
                        console.log('New Guest \nBed:'+params['bed']+"\n Date:"+params['date']);
                        App.GuestView.appendTo('#main-content .container_12');
                    },
                    connectOutlets:function(){
                        alert("hola");
                    },
                    exit: function(){
                        App.GuestsView.newGuestView.remove();
                    }
                })
            }),
            rooms:Ember.Route.extend({
                route:'/rooms',
                index:Ember.Route.extend({
                    route:'/',                    
                    connectOutlets:function(router) {
                        App.RoomsView.appendTo('#main-content .container_12');    
                    },
                    enter: function(){
                        console.log("Entro Rooms");
                    },
                    exit: function(){
                        App.RoomsView.remove();
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    });
```

Comment: That is interesting, change your newGuest:Ember.Route.transitionTo('guests.new'), to newGuest: function() {console.log("event fired");}, this will tell us if your event is actually reaching the function. Also check your brackets, they don't seem to align.

Comment: Changed it, still getting the same error.
What brackets do you mean? They seem aligned to me

Comment: I think the syntax for your action might be wrong, it should be {{action newGuest this href=true}}. This will automatically register on click.